# What does object object object mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to make a journal but can't get it to work. I'm trying to make a `for` loop that posts the posts that I compose, in an array on the home page. I get connection between the app file and the ejs file because the inputs shows up when I log it in the terminal. I just can't get it to show up on the home page. I just want the title of the input to show up, but I keep getting `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` and I can't understand why?

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<P> <%= startingContent %> </P>
<%- console.log(posts);-%>
<ul>
    
<% posts.forEach(function(post, i) { %>
 <li>Posts <%= posts %></li>
<% }); %> 
</ul>
```

```
const posts = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home",{ startingContent: homeStartingContent , posts:posts});
  posts: [
{posts: posts},
{posts: posts}
  ]
  //console.log(posts);
});
```

Comment: It means you're trying to output an object as a string. Try only outputting properties of the object which are strings/numbers?

Comment: Okay so how do I call for my variable posts? I thought  <%=  was how you did it in an ejs file?

Comment: <%= post.posts %>

Comment: what do you mean by "call for my variable"?

Comment: @danvid `posts.posts` might also be an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

[object Object] is a string version of an object instance. This value is returned by a JavaScript program if you try to print out an object without first formatting the object as a string.

This is the syntax for the [object Object] object:
[object Object] JavaScript Example
Take this example:

```js
let objA = {
 name: "christina",
 degree: "music",
 instrument: "flute"
}
```

Comment: First paragraph (2 sentences) is good, but the rest is confusing. What are you getting at with 'the syntax for the ...'? What is the 'enter code here' about? Maybe some of the issue is formatting. Is the last line supposed to be inside the code block (instead of 'enter code here')?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to output an Object as a string.

In order to print an object out you first need to parse it using `JSON.parse(myObject)`, then you can print it out and it's gonna be readable instead of just `[object Object]`.

If you wanna just  access a property you can use `myObject.myProperty` or `myObject["myProperty"]`

Comment: Why does the OP need to parse a JS object? It seems like you’re confusing objects with JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
    let x ={
        first:1,
        second:{
           third:3,
           fourth:[{
               fifth:4
           }],
           sixth:{
               seventh:5
           }
       },
        eighth:[1,2],
        ninth:[{
           tenth:10
       }]
}

console.log(x) // { first: 1, second: { third: 3, fourth: [ [Object] ],sixth: { seventh: 5 } }, eighth: [ 1, 2 ],ninth: [ { tenth: 10 } ] }
```

parsing in javascript works only till 2 level. it converts array of objects to [object, object].

```
    let x ={
        first:1,
        second:{
            third:3,
            fourth:[{
                fifth:4
            }],
            sixth:{
                seventh:5
            }
        },
        eighth:[1,2],
        ninth:[{
            tenth:10
        }]
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(x)) // {"first":1,"second":{"third":3,"fourth":[{"fifth":4}],"fi":[7],"sixth":{"seventh":5}},"eighth":[1,2],"ninth":[{"tenth":10}]}
```

try using JSON.stringify() to get the whole object

Comment: ??? Doesn’t it depend on the environment. Chrome shows all objects all the way down. No “[object Object]”